# Understanding the use of `typename` in function signature, outside template

Tags: c++, templates

Reading about iterators online, I came across this declaration of the `std::distance` function:

```
template<class InputIterator>
  typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type // What is this line?
    distance (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

The first and third lines are clear to me, but I don't entirely understand the syntax of the second line.

I understand that `iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type` will generate a class from the `iterator_traits` class template in order to figure out the `difference_type` suitable for this particular `InputIterator`. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

But what I certainly don't understand is the use of `typename` in this context. I've never seen it outside a `template < ... >` clause.

Please explain this syntax and its usage.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename

Comment: The short answer is that the compiler needs help determining that `difference_type` is a type as syntactically speaking it could be a static member variable. So `typename` is necessary to disambiguate the syntax in this case.

Comment: *"outside template"*, your are in template though...

Comment: @john I see. Because `difference_type` is a *dependent name*, since its type depends on a template argument?

Comment: @AvivCohn yes, this issue only arises with templates, with non-templates the compiler can just look at the class to determine what everything is. With dependent names in templates thats not possible in the general case.

Comment: @john Great! Got it, thank you. Voting to close.

Comment: @AvivCohn I just learned from another SO question, that C++20 is proposing to relax the rules around typename. In cases where a type is the only legal option typename will no longer be required.

Comment: @AvivCohn See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990971/why-dont-i-need-to-specify-typename-before-a-dependent-type-in-c20/61991157#61991157)