# Why don't I need to specify "typename" before a dependent type in C++20?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, typename

This bit of code compiled in C++20 (using gcc 10.1) without using the `typename` keyword before the dependent type `std::vector<T>::iterator`. Why does it compile?

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T>::iterator // Why does this not require "typename" before it?
f() { return {}; }

int main() {
    auto fptr = &f<int>;
}
```

[code playground](https://godbolt.org/z/WhSs53)

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that the standard would find it ambiguous (hence, requiring `typename`), since (I think...) it *has* to be a type there.  Might want to add `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: C++20 allows to remove some typename usage.

Comment: @Eljay It still needs to know that it _is_ a type ;) It being a type is part of how "there" is defined/recognised. Or, rather, it used to.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

One of the new features in C++20 is [Down with `typename`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html).

In C++17, you *had* to provide the `typename` keyword in nearly all<sup>†</sup> dependent contexts to disambiguate a type from a value. But in C++20, this rule is relaxed a lot. In all contexts where you *need* to have a type, the `typename` keyword is no longer mandatory.

One such context is the return type of a function in class scope, as in your example. Others include the type in a member declaration, the type on the right-hand side of a using declaration, the parameter declaration of a lambda, the type you're passing to `static_cast`, etc. See the paper for the full list.

---

<sup>†</sup> Nearly all because base-specifiers and mem-initializer-ids were always excluded, as in:

```
template <typename T> struct X : T::type  { }; // always ok
```

This is okay because, well, that *needs* to be a type. The paper simply extends this logic (well, it has to be a type, so let's just assume it's a type) to a lot more places that have to be types.

Comment: IIRC we made `typename` _optional_ already in C++11 for the base-specifiers and mem-initializer-ids. The original `typename` proposal disallowed it everywhere it wasn't required, but we believed it would be harmless to accept a redundant `typename`.

Answer (score 21):

From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names), from c++20, in contexts where the dependent name is unambiguously a typename, the `typename` keyword is no longer needed. In particular:

> A qualified name that is used as a declaration specifier in the (top-level) decl-specifier-seq of:
>
> > a simple declaration or function definition at namespace scope