# Why is `typename` prefix still required in such a case in C++20?

Tags: c++, standards, c++20, c++-concepts, typename

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61991146/508343:

> One of the new features in C++20 is ***[Down with typename](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html)***.
>
> In C++17, you had to provide the typename keyword in nearly all†
> dependent contexts to disambiguate a type from a value. But in C++20,
> this rule is relaxed a lot. ***In all contexts where you need to have a
> type, the typename keyword is no longer mandatory.***

```
template<typename T>
concept IsOK = true;

template<typename T>
requires IsOK<T::U> // error: use ‘typename T::U’
void f()
{}

struct A
{
    using U = int;
};

int main()
{
    f<A>(); 
}
```

In the code above, obviously, `IsOK` concept can take types only.

**Why is** `typename` **required here?**

See [online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4We41MEf4)

Comment: I imagine it simplifies the job of compiler writers somehow.

Comment: Template arguments are strange. I know it's not the same as this concept case, but: If the argument could be parsed as either an expression or a type (e.g. `int()`), it is always a type, no matter how the template being used is declared. On the other hand, if the argument is an injected-class-name of a class template, it could mean either the template or the current instantiation type, and the meaning does depend on the declaration of the template being used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is speaking loosely about what "context" means. What [the feature](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0634r0.pdf) is doing is finding places where it is *grammatically impossible* for anything other than a typename to appear in that location. It is those places where `typename` is no longer necessary.

For example, `using name = X;`. Grammatically, this is a type alias declaration. As such, whatever `X` is, the grammar *requires* that it be a type. If the `X` happens to be a name dependent on a template parameter, whatever that name is must be a type. So the grammar is unambiguous, and `typename` is redundant.

The syntax `name<X>` states that `X` is a template argument to the template `name`. But template arguments do not have to be types. A *specific* template may take a type as a specific argument, but *grammatically*, `X` could be an identifier referencing a variable or a template. Therefore, you must disambiguate ambiguous dependent `X`s.

Comment: but here `IsOK` was already declared as `template<typename T>`, so definitely in `IsOK<X>` X must be a type, nothing else is possible

Comment: @phuclv: That would require the validity of the code to be based on what `IsOK` is. That's my point; the paper only removes the requirement of `typename` when it is *grammatically impossible* for anything other than a typename to appear. It is not the rules of C++ grammar that require `X` in `IsOK<X>` to be a typename; it's the rules of instantiating `IsOK`. Grammar is about the structure of code; semantics like template instantiation are about the *meaning* of code.

Comment: Funny how the code would be invalid if the argument was `int()` and the parameter was `int V` for the opposite reason (`int()` taken as a type).