# Disagreement between GCC and clang about "typename" keyword

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, c++20

I was compiling the following code and [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/eT4rejh8d) seems to accept the following code.

```
#include <map>

template<typename K, typename V>
class my_map {
private:
    std::map<K, V> mmap;
public:
    typedef std::map<K, V>::iterator iterator;
    typedef std::map<K, V>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin() {return mmap.begin();}
    const_iterator begin() const {return mmap.begin();}

};

int main()
{
    my_map<int, int>::iterator whatever;
    return 0;
}
```

But [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/bcr4vvxxo) complains about the missing `typename` keyword.
The complaint of clang makes more sense to me. Is this a GCC bug?

**Edit**: Obviously, [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) **does not** answer my question, as I am not asking what `typename` keyword is, but asking about different behaviors of compilers.

**Edit**: Now the program is accepted by both clang(from version 16) and gcc.

Comment: IIRC this stuff is dependent on the version of C++ you are compiling for. Which version are you using?

Comment: I can't remember what version relaxes these rules (pretty sure it is C++20) but I know for sure that in C++17 and older you need the typename.  If you want your code to be backwards compatible I would keep the `typename`

Comment: I am using C++20

Comment: More likely to be a g++ *extension* than a bug.

Comment: @AdrianMole   Then I would suppose that clang should behave similarly.

Comment: Can confirm, clang bug as it is a C++20 feature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990971/why-dont-i-need-to-specify-typename-before-a-dependent-type-in-c20

Comment: *Then I would suppose that clang should behave similarly.*  Why would you suppose that?  They are different compilers, being maintained by different people, who are at different places in supporting C++20.  Supporting C++20 is still a work-in-progress for Clang, GCC, VS's CL.EXE, and most/all other C++ vendors.

Comment: MSVC accepts the code without `typename` if using C++20 (but not with C++17). @NathanOliver

Comment: @Elijay In case the behavior is defined by the standard, shouldn't we expect that it should be implemented accordingly in both compilers?

Comment: @AdrianMole Woot.  For once it's not MSVC getting it wrong ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver I would call this unimplemented feature not a bug, since support for C++20 is still under development. [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20#C.2B.2B14_library_features) this feature is marked as unimplemented by clang yet.

Comment: But it's 2022, already. :(

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan Oh, i see :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> asking about different behaviors of compilers.

It seems that Clang has not implemented this C++20 feature yet. This can be seen from [compiler support documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20#C.2B.2B14_library_features). This means clang is **not standard compliant**.

| C++20 feature | Paper(s) | GCC | Clang | MSVC | Apple Clang |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Allow lambda-capture [=, this] | P0409R2 | 8 | 6 | 19.22* | 10.0.0* |
| Make `typename` more optional | P0634R3 | 9 |  | 19.29 (16.10)* |  |
| Pack expansion in lambda init-capture | P0780R2 | 9 | 9 | 19.22* | 11.0.3* |

---

As we can see in the above above table, the entry for clang corresponding to "Make typename more optional" is blank.

On the other hand GCC and MSVC have implemented this C++20 feature and so are **standard compliant**. [GCC and MSVC Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EvqfoP67r)

---

#### Update

As of 03/11/2022, clang supports this with **version 16** as shown in the updated table below:

| C++20 feature | Paper(s) | GCC | Clang | MSVC | Apple Clang |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Allow lambda-capture [=, this] | P0409R2 | 8 | 6 | 19.22* | 10.0.0* |
| Make `typename` more optional | P0634R3 | 9 | 16 | 19.29 (16.10)* |  |
| Pack expansion in lambda init-capture | P0780R2 | 9 | 9 | 19.22* | 11.0.3* |

The program [compiles with clang trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/bb9vvMerq).