# missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name on Ubuntu Clang only

Tags: c++, linux, clang

I've started using GitHub actions however I can't compile my program. It builds just fine on Ubuntu GCC but clang (it works fine on my macOS machine using clang but not on this ubuntu) throws this error:

```
Run cmake --build /home/runner/work/xenon-lang/xenon-lang/build --config Release
[  1%] Building CXX object XeUtils/CMakeFiles/XenonUtils.dir/BaseProgram.cxx.o
In file included from /home/runner/work/xenon-lang/xenon-lang/XeUtils/BaseProgram.cxx:19:
In file included from /home/runner/work/xenon-lang/xenon-lang/XeUtils/BaseProgram.hxx:22:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/string:48:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/bits/stl_iterator.h:2618:35: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'iterator_traits<_It>::iterator_category'
      { using iterator_category = iterator_traits<_It>::iterator_category; };
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/runner/work/xenon-lang/xenon-lang/XeUtils/BaseProgram.cxx:19:
In file included from /home/runner/work/xenon-lang/xenon-lang/XeUtils/BaseProgram.hxx:22:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/string:55:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/bits/basic_string.tcc:593:34: error: expected expression
      auto __r = std::move(__op)(auto(__p), auto(__n));
                                 ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/bits/basic_string.tcc:593:45: error: expected expression
      auto __r = std::move(__op)(auto(__p), auto(__n));
                                            ^
3 errors generated.
gmake[2]: *** [XeUtils/CMakeFiles/XenonUtils.dir/build.make:76: XeUtils/CMakeFiles/XenonUtils.dir/BaseProgram.cxx.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:269: XeUtils/CMakeFiles/XenonUtils.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

I was thinking that `In file included from /home/runner/work/xenon-lang/xenon-lang/XeUtils/BaseProgram.hxx:22:` will show me what the erorr is but that line in my code is

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: What clang versions you are using (mac/ubuntu)? Did you set the proper C++ standard version?

Comment: You are trying to compile something that should be compiled in C++23 mode with an earlier mode or a compiler that doesn't support the relevant C++23 features yet.

Comment: Seems like [Disagreement between GCC and clang about "typename" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72993691/disagreement-between-gcc-and-clang-about-typename-keyword)

Comment: So you seem to be using a Clang version that is too old for the libstdc++ version. You generally can't use newer libstdc++ version with older Clang versions (although I think the other way around should generally be fine).