# Dependent names vs non-dependent names

Tags: c++, templates

In the following example:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyList {
    typedef std::list<T> type1;
};

template<typename T>
class MyList2 {
    typename MyList<T>::type1 type2;
};
```

I thought that both type1 and type2 are dependent name since both of their types depend on the template parameter. However, why is the first one considered non-dependent since I can use `typedef` with it?

Comment: In the first case, a compiler knows that `T` is a type and that `std::list` is a class template that takes a type template parameter. There is no ambiguity. In the second case, a compiler doesn't know what `::type1` refers to. It could be a type, it could be a static data member. That's why you need `typename` only in the second case.

Comment: BTW, both `type1` and `type2` are dependent name :)

Comment: Your question is probably not what you intended to ask. It seems that you intent to ask why `typename` is required for the second part, but not the first. That's not related to whether or not `type1` and `type2` are dependent names.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, I check the explanations on cppreference again. Although both `std::list<T>` and `MyList<T>::type1` are both dependent on T,  the former is for sure a type while the second is not. So the key should be whether the name is already established as a type. Is that correct?

Comment: This depends on context, too. `typename` should not be used if a dependent type is specified as a base class. Starting from C++20, `typename` [becomes optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990971/why-dont-i-need-to-specify-typename-before-a-dependent-type-in-c20) in other contexts where only a type can appear.

Comment: @Evg Can you elaborate on `typename` should not be used if a dependent type is specified as a base class?

Comment: `template<class T> class Derived : public BaseSelector<T>::Type { ... };`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dependent name is, in C++ terms, a name whose grammatical properties are dependent on a template parameter.

Names can mean a lot of different things in C++, and the grammatical location where a name can be used depends on certain properties of that name. In order to understand what `X x;` is trying to do, the compiler needs to know what `X` is at this point in the program. If `X` names a type, then this is declaring a variable named `x`. The compiler doesn't need to know everything about `X`, but grammatically, in order to even begin to make sense of this text, the compiler does need to know that `X` here names a type.

`std::list` is the name of a class template; the compiler can easily see that because that's how it is declared. It doesn't need to have the body of the declaration; `template<typename T> class list;` is sufficient. `std::list<T>` is an instantiation of a class template, so just from the declaration, the compiler knows that this is the name of a type.

However, `MyList<T>::type1` now requires more than just the declaration of the `MyList` template. It requires actually *instantiating* that template. And if `T` is itself a template parameter of the current code (as is the case for `MyList2`), then instantiation at the point of initially compiling the code is impossible. That instantiation must be delayed until `MyList2` is itself given a concrete `T` to work with.

But the compiler still has to make sense of this code: `typename MyList<T>::type1 type2;`. And to do that, it needs some idea of what `MyList<T>::type1` actually is. *Without* instantiating `MyList<T>`.

Which is why you have to tell it that it is a `typename`.

Answer (score 1):

While `std::list<T>` uses `T`, it does not depend on `T`.  The name `std::list` exists as long as `<list>` is included.

On the other hand `typename MyList<T>::type1 type2;` does depend on `T` as there is no way to know what `type1` is without instantiating `MyList<T>`.  That is why you have to use `typename` as the grammar by default will consider `type1` to be a member variable or member function, not a type.