# What is the difference of using `typename` in the following?

Tags: c++, templates, return-type, function-templates, typename

What is the difference between using "`typename`" before the return type of a function and without using it at the declaration of a function like the following below?

And what is different if we don't use it at all?

```
template< class T > typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t );
template< class T > std::remove_reference_t<T>&& move( T&& t ) ;
```

Comment: The presence of `typename` is not the only difference between those two declarations.

Comment: Hint: look at the definition of `std::remove_reference_t`

Comment: any direct answer, please :(

Comment: Did you try to remove it and see what happens?

Comment: @molbdnilo . I did - but how do you know :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the purpose of using '`typename`' keyword right before the return type of a function?

In `std::remove_reference<T>::type`, the `::type` is dependent on the template type `T`. The compiler (until C++20), doesn't know this, and one needs to tell that, so that compiler understands it is a type. That is the reason why `typename` keyword is.

Read more: ***[When is the "typename" keyword necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary)***

The second  `std::remove_reference_t<T>`, is a [template type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), which looks like:

```
template< class T >
using remove_reference_t = typename remove_reference<T>::type; (since C++14)
```

And allows you to save some typing (aka. for convenience).

---

> What is different if we don't use it at all?

[Since C++20, you can simply write with or without `typename` keyword](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4aEKd6aWa), prior to that compiler may not interpret it as a type.

Read more:
***[Why don't I need to specify "typename" before a dependent type in C++20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990971/why-dont-i-need-to-specify-typename-before-a-dependent-type-in-c20)***

Comment: thank a lot! that answer explains everything!

Answer (score 2):

> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename
>
> (2nd point in the link)
>
> - Inside a declaration or a definition of a template, typename can be used to declare that a dependent qualified name is a type.

When you are using `foo_type::bar`, the compiler can't ensure what `bar` is, maybe a member variable or a type or anything else. Hence you have to at a precede `typename` to hint to the compiler that it is a typename.

Comment: If `foo_type` is dependent on a template parameter. Also you don't mention what the differences between the two declarations are.

Comment: I wanted to say, without `typename`, the code is uncompilable. But @JeJo mentioned that it's correct only if the standard before c++20, and he provided lots of detail explanation and related articles too. I think this answer is actually too simple.